# How to get better ImageView resize quality?

Tags: javafx, resize, imageview, scale

Images scaled in JavaFX using `setFitWidth()`/`setFitHeight()` methods have significantly inferior quality compared to images prescaled in graphics editor, in my case Photoshop.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Image Resize Test");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gray;");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView("save.png");
        //ImageView imageView = new ImageView("save_small.png");
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.setFitHeight(15);
        root.getChildren().add(imageView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Application screenshots:
[image]
[image].

Image on the left is scaled in JavaFX, and the image on the right is prescaled in Photoshop. The first image has white border clearly visible only on its right side, while the second image (resized in Photoshop) has faint border visible on all sides, which better represents the original image that has white border all around it.

I tried setting `imageView.setSmooth(true)` and `SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED`, but results are the same.

---

These are PNG images used in this example:

Scaled (15x15) PNG image (resized in Photoshop):
[image]

Original (500x509) PNG image:
[image]

Comment: Are they always going to be shown scaled? In that case you should probably scale them beforehand

Comment: I think you're running into a bug where the width or height of the image is off by one pixel when preserve ratio is used (a rounding error).  Try turning of "preserve ratio" and specify the desired width and height directly.